# Passing a variable as reference to a function and updating the same variable with the functions return value

Tags: c++

I have a variable that I am passing as a constant reference to a function. I then used the same variable to update the return value.

Sample code below

```
//function declaration
Error func(int x, const Error& status);

//function call
Error status; 
status = func(x, status);
```

I know this sounds complicated and hard to read, but I would want to know if there can be any technical difficulties implementing my code like this. what are the drawbacks and if there is a scenario where this could lead to errors.

Comment: This seems fitter on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, but make sure to check the [tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) and the  [How to ask](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: This is a valid, albeit strange, design. There will be no tricky aliasing issues here. More canonically you would pass `status` by non-const reference and just mutate it within the function.

Comment: @CoryKramer I think there are valid reasons for wanting to not allow an *implicit* change to a passed argument, yet still allow the caller to *explicitly* modify a local variable, should that be appropriate.